# Intelligent talking peacock, scientist, boy, bad man, filter/tap to brain, ripping out feathers

Tags: story-identification

In the summer of 1984 (or there around) a book was read on national Norwegian radio.  I don't think it was originally in Norwegian, but I don't know from where it was - nor it's title or author.  I only heard a few parts, it's long ago, and I was about 10 at the time.  I guess it's not *really* a sci-fi or fantasy book - but it surely had sci-fi elements to it...  But I guess the focus was more on friendship and some suspense.  Probably a child or youth book.  I guess the book may have been from the early 1980s...

It's about a peacock which a scientist had modified to become very intelligent and able to talk.  A filter - sort of a tap - is placed in the peacock's neck(?), which inhibits neural-impulses and makes the peacock dumber.  This filter somewhat malfunctions, so the peacock periodically falls into states of stupidity - where it's basically just slowly repeating back what's it's being told.

For some reason - possibly money problems - the scientist must give-up the peacock to the stories bad-guy.  He abuses the peacock and uses it's periods of stupidity - where it's basically just repeating back what's it's told - to agree to give up tail-feathers, which the bad man rips-out to give as gifts to his girlfriends.

Not sure where the hero - the boy - comes in...  Perhaps the son of the scientist or someone visiting the scientist?  Anyway, the boy steals the peacock from the bad man, and runs away.  At the time, the peacock is a sorry sight, and only have a few tail-feathers left.

I don't think I heard much more of the story, but I assume the boy and peacock ran away - across country - with the bad man (and possibly the authorities) after them.

I know it's not much - and not much of sci-fi/fantasy - but I thought it was worth a shot...